# Swift: CollectionView's indexPath.row doesn't increase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My logic is simple: I want to build an App like Instagram. For the "Feed/Main" page, I am using UICollection View with custom layout like Pinterest.

My first thought is fetching posts. my fetchPosts() function is

```
  func fetchPosts(){
        // Temporaly just fetch all posts.
        // guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        POSTS_REF.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else {return}
            for fetchedPost in dictionary{
                let postId = fetchedPost.key
                let postDictionary = fetchedPost.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                guard let userId = postDictionary["userId"] else {return}

                self.fetchUser(withUid: userId as! String) { (user) in
                    let postImageUrl = postDictionary["photoUrl"] as! String
                    self.loadImage(with: postImageUrl) { (image) in

                        let post = Post(createdBy: user, postId: postId, image: image, dictionary: postDictionary)

                        CONSTANT_FeedCollectionVC?.posts.append(post)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            CONSTANT_FeedCollectionVC?.collectionView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But my problem is after I successfully push a new post, and back to Feed page. From the print log information, the number of items indeed increased by one, but the indexPath.row doesn't increase.

I tried to print the number of items and the index path and the count of posts array as the following, but the result shows that
count: 0
count: 1
Index: 0 Posts count: 2
count: 3
Index: 0 Posts count: 3

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("count:",posts.count)
        return posts.count

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("Index: ",indexPath.row," Posts count: ",posts.count)

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCollectionCell
        // The delegate should
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.addShadow()
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }
```

I have 3 posts but Index.row stoped at 0?! I wrote the fetchPost() function in a FirebaseService Class and called in FeedViewController. CONSTANT_FeedCollectionVC is just a constant "var CONSTANT_FeedCollectionVC : FeedCollectionVC?".

```
class FeedCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CONSTANT_FeedCollectionVC = self

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? MyLayoutForFeed {
            layout.delegate = self
        }

        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        FirebaseService.shared.fetchPosts()

    }
```

Please save me out of here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `posts.count` is increasing, which means that your model is getting updated. The `cellForItemAt` is only called, though, for rows that are visible. You shouldn’t see it called for cells 1 and 2 unless those are scrolled into view.

So, one of two things is happening:

1. Perhaps only the cell for `indexPath.item` of 0 is currently visible (e.g. is this a full screen cell where cells 1 and 2 are not visible yet?). You shouldn’t expect to see `indexPath.item` of 1 or 2 until you scroll those cells into view.
2. If cells 1 and 2 should be visible but you’re not seeing `cellForItemAt` called for those cells, then perhaps there is a problem with your custom `MyLayoutForFeed`. If that’s not a simple flow layout subclass, but rather a completely custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, its [`layoutAttributesForElements(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements) will dictate what cells it considers visible within that `CGRect`. It’s possible that it’s not correctly identifying that cells 1 and 2 should be shown within that `CGRect`.

Comment: Yes, after make sure my cell 1 and 2 are both visible, I solved the problem in MyLayoutForFeed file. It is a complete custom flow layout and I wrongly used a "If" closure to stop the presence of cell 1, 2 inside the override prepare(). Thanks for your help.